# Match alignment of list bullets with text in `<div>`

Tags: html, css

I am injecting html from an editor into my site. How can I 'inherit' the alignment from a child element like this:

```
<li>
  <div align="right">one</div>
</li>
```

the issue is that the bullets are aligned left and text is right , I would like to get the alignment from whatever is set on the div in this case 'right'. This can be different since it is coming from an html-editor.

css:

```
 ul, ol, li {
list-style: disc !important;
}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bfu20zhq/

Comment: So you want the parent bullet to have the same alignment as the child `div`? Will there be more than one child `div`?

Comment: yes see jsfiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to select a parent according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/1014958#1014958) and the MDN has nothing to suggest that this has changed recently.

However, as indicated in related posts, this can be achieved through javascript (and must be, since css can't do it yet). You can do this by walking the DOM tree and finding all the `div` elements that have a parent `li` and then make their `align` attributes the same:

```
// create the filter for the tree walker

var div_filter = {
    acceptNode: function (node) {
        if ( node.tagName == 'DIV' && node.parentElement.tagName == 'LI' ) {

             return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;

        }
    }
};

// create the tree walker so we can
// find all the divs

var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker( document.body, 
                                            NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, 
                                            div_filter, 
                                            false);


// walk the DOM tree for the nodes we want
// and make the `li` elements have the same `align` as the `div`s
while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    console.log(treeWalker.currentNode);
    treeWalker.currentNode.parentElement.setAttribute('align', 
                                    /* fetch the div's align attribute */
                                    treeWalker.currentNode.getAttribute('align') );
}
```

Unfortunately, while this correctly sets the `align` attribute, it doesn't give the desired result as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfu20zhq/14/). *I'm leaving this here however because we need it for the full solution.*

Setting `float: right` on the list elements has an effect, but a horrible one.

After a bit of tweaking, I found that adding `inside` to `list-style` and adjusting `text-align` to `right` or `left` accordingly, the desired result is achieved:

This is what we want, if the `div` has `align = "right"`

```
li {
    list-style: disc inside;
    text-align: right;
}
```

We also need to change the `div`s to `display: inline-block` so they don't act like non-text elements:

```
li > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to align the bullets vertically, you need to give the `div`s a definite `width`, such as `width: 30%` or something like that.

So our `while` loop changes to:

```
while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    console.log(treeWalker.currentNode);
    treeWalker.currentNode.parentElement.style.textAlign = 
                 treeWalker.currentNode.getAttribute('align');
}
```

Here is the [complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfu20zhq/16/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same alignment simply add "list-style-position: inside;" to your css [like this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bfu20zhq/15/)

```
li 
{
list-style: disc;
list-style-position: inside;
}
```